# Radio button not taking the value as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Below are my HTML and javascript codes:

HTML

```
<body>
       
        <div>
            <form id="radioform">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="mainbox">
                        <label for="gender"><strong>Gender</strong></label><br> 
                    </div>

                    <div id="optionbox">
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" /> Female
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
                    </div> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
var genderval = "null";

const form = document.getElementById("radioform");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDeafult();
    genderval = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
});

console.log(genderval); //test

if(genderval === "female") {
    console.log("Female");

} else if(genderval === "male") {
    console.log("Male");
}
```

It only prints out "null" no matter which radio button I select.
It seems like checked is not working properly in the querySelector but I do not understand why.

(var genderval = "null"; is just for the testing. It returns me an uncaught reference error when I delete the line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `let genderval;` to define your variable. It's `e.preventDefault();`. Also, put your [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement inside the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

```js
let genderval;

const form = document.getElementById("radioform");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    genderval = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
    if (genderval === "female") {
        console.log("Female");
    } else if (genderval === "male") {
        console.log("Male");
    }
});

console.log(genderval); //test
```

```html
<div>
    <form id="radioform">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="mainbox">
                <label for="gender"><strong>Gender</strong></label><br>
            </div>
            <div id="optionbox">
              <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" /> Female 
              <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
          </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-btn" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The variable is `undefined` at first, but once you check any of both radio buttons and click on "submit", it'll print the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a slight spelling mistake, it would be failing at `e.preventDeafult();` as correct method is `e.preventDefault();`.
2. Since console logs are used outside of addEventListener block, they will get triggered when script.js file is loaded and hence when submit event is triggered, it will always show null. To fix this issue, console logs can be shifted inside addEventListener like below

```
    var genderval = "null";
    const form = document.getElementById("radioform");
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        genderval = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
        console.log(genderval);
        if (genderval === "female") {
            console.log("Female");
        } else if (genderval === "male") {
            console.log("Male");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your answer and mine? I don't see a significant difference :-)

Comment: @LightningMcQueen The difference is that there's an extra `console.log(genderval);` and the `genderval` variable starts with the string `"null"` instead of being `undefined`.

Comment: That could be a *comment* on my answer, not a whole new answer, and I did mention that `genderval` variable is going to be `undefined` at first in my answer, and the extra `console.log` is, I mean, trivial. I'm still new here and I don't know *all* the rules, but at a first guess, this could be a comment however I would/may ask such a question on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) but I'm not really here to make trouble, anyway good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have radio buttons with the same name (here `gender`), the value of the selected radio button can be accessed from the object named `gender`.

If you set a `required` attribute on (just) one of the radio buttons you need to pick one of the radio buttons in that list (`gender`) to make the submit action on the form.

In general, remove all the IDs from the form and use the name attribute instead. Names do not have to be unique like the IDs throughout the HTML document and they can be used for accessing the form fields when you know the form.

```js
document.forms.radioform.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let genderval = e.target.gender.value;
  if (genderval === "female") {
    console.log("Female");
  } else if (genderval === "male") {
    console.log("Male");
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="radioform">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Gender</legend>
      <div id="optionbox">
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required /> Female</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```